# Failing to diff some subdirectories' files

Tags: diff

I am using the diff command to compare directory and subdirectories' files like so:

```
 diff -bBE ./dir/* ../parent/dir/* >> diff.txt
```

But I am getting that :

```
 diff: extra operand `./dir/somefile'
```

The two directory and subdirectories' files are structured exactly the same way but their content is different. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is expanded by the shell, becoming (potentially) multiple arguments to `diff`.  Just get rid of the `*`s; `diff` already knows how to handle directories.

Comment: Great, thanks ! it worked, I made diff -bBrE ./dir/ ../parent/dir/ >> diff.txt

Comment: That's kind of a weird specification. Why not just allow the star?